# Why is my disk space suddenly full?

Tags: raspbian

Suddenly, my disk is full and I don't really know why. How can I find out?

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs           3749072 3558828         0 100% /
/dev/root        3749072 3558828         0 100% /
devtmpfs           86184       0     86184   0% /dev
tmpfs              18888     700     18188   4% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs              37760       0     37760   0% /run/shm
/dev/mmcblk0p1     57288   18904     38384  33% /boot
tmpfs              37760   37760         0 100% /tmp
```

Also, what is this `/dev/mmcblk0p1`?

Comment: To answer your second question: `/boot` is the Raspberry Pi's boot partition and it is mounted on `/dev/mmcblk0p1` which is the 1st partition of your SD card device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [du](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) command will list the disk used.

Comment: thanks, it seems most of space is in 977852  ./var/cache/apt/archives
1012728 ./var/cache/apt
1019392 ./var/cache
1306768 ./var
1899548 ./usr
3441844 .

Comment: apt-get clean command clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. To clear the cache, type the following: `sudo apt-get clean`

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer to the 2nd question asked, namely what is `/dev/mmcblk0p1`.

This is the 1st partition of the SD card and the file system `/boot` is mounted on that partition.  `/boot` is the Raspberry Pi's boot partition.

If you run `sudo fdisk -l` you will see all of the partitions on your system, here's what's on my Pi:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 31.9 GB, 31914983424 bytes
4 heads, 16 sectors/track, 973968 cylinders, total 62333952 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00014d34

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1            8192      122879       57344    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2          122880    62333951    31105536   83  Linux
```

If you `cat /etc/fstab` you will see where the file systems are mounted, for my Pi:

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```